# Display javascript array in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am trying to make a basic to do application.

Here is what I have done so far;

- When the user clicks a button a prompt appears asking the user to enter a task.
- The task will then be stored in an array
- I have displayed the array in the console. However, I am having trouble displaying the array on the web page:

```js
var toDoItems = [];
var parsed = "";

document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function() {
  var userInput = prompt("Enter your Todo: ")
  toDoItems.push = userInput;
  console.log(toDoItems);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Tasks</h1>
  <button id="addItem">Add item</button>
  <div id="item-list">
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can display the array list like this : $('#item-list').html(toDoItems.toString()); This will give you comma seperated values of that array

Comment: Loop over the array. Inside the loop, create a html element from the todo item. Insert the created html into the page.

Comment: `$()` will only work if he's actually using JQuery, which this question isn't tagged as.

Comment: He's included a link to jquery in his head

Comment: Just as a side note: `Array.push()` is a function so you have to write it like this: `toDoItems.push(userInput);`

Answer (score 5):

The first thing is you need to use `Array.push()` and not `Array.push = someVal`. Then you can loop over to the values and create a list of elements in the HTML:

```js
var toDoItems = [];
var parsed = "";

document.getElementById("addItem").onclick = function() {
  var nHTML = '';
  var userInput = prompt("Enter your Todo: ")

  toDoItems.push(userInput);
  toDoItems.forEach(function(item) {
    nHTML += '<li>' + item + '</li>';
  });

  document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML = '<ul>' + nHTML + '</ul>'
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>To Do List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>My Tasks</h1>
  <button id="addItem">Add item</button>
  <div id="item-list">
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: +1 for an easy to read answer. Also in case you didn't know: Code-Snippets have an inbuild autoformat button: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI5af.png

Comment: @FabianN. you are correct. I did not know that :). Thanks

Comment: It took more than a week of reviewing edit suggestions and first posts until I started suspecting that people in general (not just new users) just don't know about the button or better, they don't recognize it as the *auto format code*-button... So I made a picture of it... But you are the first one who confirmed my suspicion =)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **map()** to map over the toDoItems and convert each items to html code and then use **join()** to combine the array into one string of HTML code.

Like this:

```
const HTML = toDoItems.map( item => `<li>${item}</li> ` ).join('');
document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML = '<ul>' + HTML + '</ul>'
```

Edit: Fixed typo (should be join, not joint)

Answer (score 1):

Loop over `toDoItems`, create a `<p>` tag and append it to `#item-list`:

```
toDoItems.forEach((item) => {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerText = item;
    document.querySelector('#item-list').appendChild(p); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `innerHTML` for this

```
document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML += "<p>" +userInput+"</p>";
```

demo : [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jPaP79UkKSs6SpxVqBBG?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Check below I think this may help you
I removed style from your code for my convenience

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <script>
        function myFunction(){
        var toDoItems = [];
         var parsed ="";
        var userInput = prompt("Enter your Todo: ")
        toDoItems.push = userInput;
        document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML=userInput;
        console.log(toDoItems);
    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Tasks</h1>
        <button id="addItem" onclick="myFunction()">Add item</button>
        <div id="item-list">
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

The Code above has an drawback: It erases the old value of userInput when you enter a new value in prompt().
I propose:
document.getElementById("item-list").innerHTML +=userInput+"
";
Vu

Comment: It's me: += userInput+"<br />";  (the last line)

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).